# PyCharm - Defining custom recognized import aliases?

Tags: python, pycharm, alias

In PyCharm, I can type `np.array`, and if I haven't imported NumPy yet, PyCharm gives me a simple click to automatically write the import line. In particular, PyCharm knows that `np` is referring to `numpy` and will add the appropriate `import numpy as np`.

Is there a way to define my own alias names to be recognized? For example, `tensorflow` is usually imported as `tf`. PyCharm doesn't know this by default though, and so doesn't give me the automatic import completion. Any way to do this? Thanks you much!

Comment: Interesting. This certainly does not happen to my installation of PyCharm Community edition. Is it a professional edition feature?

Comment: Does it really work for numpy?

Comment: @warmoverflow: If it's not working for you, probably. PyCharm Professional is free for students, so I'm working with that currently. (If you might just be missing it, here is how to do it: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Intention+actions+and+quick+fixes)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yes, but it would seem only for the professional version based on warmoverflow's comment.

Comment: @golmschenk I have the pro version but I only get `theano.xxx.np` and `sympy.xxx.np`, basically anything ending in .np , do you have any plugin installed that may be doing something different?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I don't have anything special that I know of. If I type np.array without having the import statement, np will be highlighted by the red scribble and a red lightbulb icon should appear when you move your cursor to that part of the code. You can then either click the red lightbulb to add the import or press alt+enter.

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, this is very delayed, but this does work for NumPy. As of PyCharm 2019.3 Professional, if you create a project with an empty virtual environment, and create a file containing only `np.array([1, 2, 3])`, PyCharm will offer to import numpy as np. If you have another package installed which has a version of `np` in it, PyCharm no longer offers `import numpy as np` but instead offers the version in that other package (e.g., with `plotly` installed `plotly.figure_factory.np` will be offered).

Comment: This JetBrains issue is related, and worth voting on: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30031