Can I add abbreviations for imports to PyCharm?
There is a number of industry-accepted import abbreviations, such as import pandas as pd, and there's a number of abbreviation conventions on our project. Is there a way to add them to PyCharm, so that I could type, say mm.Schema, command-click on the mm and have PyCharm add import marshmallow as mm or suggest that import when I type import marshmallow?

Honestly I have been working with PyCharm for like 5 years and honestly I have never encountered such feature. It is definitely possible if you re-write the core settings but as "user friendly" option there is nothing. (I still may be wrong).

https://stackoverflow.com/q/35901598/3001761
